# How to add "Add to wishlist" button next to Add to Cart?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How to add "Add to wishlist" button next to Add to Cart like the one in the picture?[image]

Answer (score 0):

By turning template path hints you can see the respective template file for these buttons, which is addto.phtml in your theme pakg / theme

You will see 2 button there, see classes used for those button. Find that classes in appropriate css file in your theme pakg/ theme. There might be clear property in li tag which you could remove and try.